# My PHP newline beginner code isn't going to a new line. Little help?

Tags: php, newline

Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <Head>
    <?php   
    $name = "Sergio";
    ?>
    </Head>
    <body>
        <h1>It works!</h1>
        <?php 
        echo "So someone tells me your name is " . $name . ".";
        echo "Welcome to the site, " . $name . "\n";    
        echo "THEN WHO WAS NEW LINE?";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything outputs to a single line with no newline. Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `<br />` because you are outputing on the **browser** which needs html tags.

```
 echo "So someone tells me your name is " . $name . "<br />";
 echo "Welcome to the site, " . $name . "<br />";    
 echo "THEN WHO WAS NEW LINE?" . "<br />";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help however, if I use the \n on a string variable, it'll output to a newline right?

Comment: "\n" will output a newline in the source (or in files if you're going to write to files). However, "\n" is ignored by HTML, you'll need the <BR> tag in HTML to get a newline. Note also that '\n' will write the characters '\' and 'n' to the output. "\n" will write a newline. (notic the difference between single and double quotes).

Answer (score 2):

HTML ignores all newlines, so you'll have to use `<br />` to insert a line break.

Answer (score 1):

HTML isn't plain text. When you want a line break, you have to insert it with markup, such as `<br>`... though probably separate paragraphs would be more appropriate.

Also since HTML isn't plain text, you need to HTML-escape it when you output it. It doesn't matter for “Sergio”, but it would matter if someone's name was “Brian <i> Smith”, the guy with the unusual middle name who would turn your whole page italic if you didn't escape it properly.

```
<body>
    <h1>It works!</h1>
    <p>
        So someone tells me your name is <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>.
    </p>
    <p>
        Welcome to the site, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>.
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you nest string in **pre** tags then **/n** will work.

```
echo "<pre>line one\nline two</pre>";
```

but font will not be same as non pre'ed text

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<Head> 
<?php    
$name = "Sergio"; 
?> 
</Head> 
<body> 
    <h1>It works!</h1> 
    <?php  
    echo "So someone tells me your name is " . $name . ". "; 
    echo "Welcome to the site, " . $name . "<br/>";     
    echo "THEN WHO WAS NEW LINE?"; 
    ?> 
</body>
```

I would put a breakline instead will do what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If your not running it through a web browser you can echo or printf "\n"