# How to make my chat div's appear below each other

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a small chat and I am having issues making the div's appear below each other. This is what I have:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 5)
{
echo "<div class='MyChatholders'>";
 echo "<div class='pro_pic'>";
  //my image
 echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='ChatInfo'>";
//my information
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<br />";

$i++;
}
```

MY CSS:

```
div.MyChatholders
{
left: 5px;
color: black;
width: 290px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
div.pro_pic
{
left: 5px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border: solid black 1px; 
}
div.ChatInfo
{
color: black;
font-size: 14px;
left: 40px;
width: 245px;
}
```

**Please note that the (while function) is just to simulate the information drawn from the DBase.**

Now my issues is that all the div's are in one position. I would like them to fall below each other. I do not understand why this is happening. Can someone help me with my code and explain why?

I have looked at this solution but it is not working for me [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925741/how-can-i-make-my-divs-appear-below-each-other)

Comment: Sounds possible that your chat holders are absolutely positioned, causing them to stack up against each other because they have exactly the same XY coordinates on the screen. Can you verify that? Are there other CSS styles that are applying to the `MyChatholders` div?

Comment: Is there more CSS that might be involved? As shown, this *does* result in a vertical list of divs.

Comment: @Terry That was my first impression so I verified that there is no other css with the same name that may conflict with the **MyChatholders**

Comment: @PaulRoub There is a main css but like I explain to Terry I checked that no other div have the same class name.

Comment: Highly impossible - did you check with an Inspector for all the computed styles for the chat holders? I tried to replicate your issue with a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/Ev3Jt/), no luck.

Comment: There are all sorts of ways CSS could be affecting those divs without mentioning them explicitly - rules affecting children of MyChatholders' parents, etc.

Comment: @PaulRoub That was what I was thinking - the only way is to check the computed style of the element. I'm pretty sure there is something else affected the `<div>`s

Comment: checking my main CSS Now

Comment: @Terry I have seen the fiddle and that is exactly what I want let me inspect all my css....thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to your `div`s.

Working fiddle based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/MmGyU/1/

Note: Borders in the fiddle are for demonstration purposes.

```
div.MyChatholders {
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    color: black;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
div.pro_pic {
    position:relative;
    left: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
div.ChatInfo {
    position:relative;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 245px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I had tried `position: relative;` but I only added it to my Chatholder. Working now

Answer (score -1):

Make it print your `<div>` tags to a new line in your loop using `\n`

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 5)
{
echo "<div class='MyChatholders'>\n";
 echo "<div class='pro_pic'>\n";
  //my image
 echo "</div>\n";
echo "<div class='ChatInfo'>\n";
//my information
echo "</div>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
echo "<br />\n";

$i++;
}
```

**EDIT** Syntax was wrong, the `\n` needs to be within quotes

**2nd EDIT** My mistake, `\n` is not HTML and it won't work. You could use `<br />` instead according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257468/my-php-newline-beginner-code-isnt-going-to-a-new-line-little-help)

Comment: I place the `\n` in the quotes and it give me a list of \n

Comment: Okay i understand why, `\n` is not HTML so it won't work. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257468/my-php-newline-beginner-code-isnt-going-to-a-new-line-little-help says to use `<br />` instead.

Answer (score -2):

Add `clear:both;` to your chat divs.